# Number of occurrences between datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import datetime
import numpy as np
stock = '^GSPC'
start = datetime.date(2000,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()
data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo',start, end)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
data['pct_day']= data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
```

How can I find the number of occurrences of value over 0.05 in column `pct_day` and the date when it occurred?

--Edit 1:
In the comment i was suggested :

```
df[data['pct_day'].gt(0.005)]
```

which produces the following series:

```
Date
2001-01-03    True
2002-07-24    True
2002-07-29    True
2008-09-30    True
2008-10-13    True
2008-10-28    True
2008-11-13    True
2008-11-21    True
2008-11-24    True
2008-12-16    True
2009-03-10    True
2009-03-23    True
Name: pct_day, dtype: bool
```

But when i use:

```
df[data['pct_day'].gt(0.03)]
```

it produces the following series:

```
Date
2000-03-16    False
2000-04-17    False
2000-04-25    False
2000-05-30    False
2000-10-13    False
              ...  
2011-10-27    False
2011-11-30    False
2015-08-26    False
2018-12-26    False
2019-01-04    False
Name: pct_day, Length: 66, dtype: bool
```

Why is it including the ones with False in the last example but not the first one? Does the length of the second which is 66, also include `False`? I ask this because data has over 5000 entries but the length in the last example is 66.

Comment: `data['pct_day'].gt(0.05).sum()`

Comment: `gt(0.05)` returns `True` if values is greater than `0.05`. Then `sum` of all `True` gives you count of the intances.

Comment: @QuangHoang How can i ignore all the False ?

Comment: `True=1`, `False=0`. Sum means ignoring the `False`.

Comment: @QuangHoang how can i ignore False from showing up? On the True ones show up?

Comment: `df[data['pct_day'].gt(0.05)]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang `Date
1999-12-31    False
2000-01-03    False
2000-01-04    False
 `
I would like `False` to be omitted and just `True` to be shown. Thanks! Also if you could kindly put it in an answer, i will be able to mark it solved!